# How to pass state between all child components after user authorization?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

The server is returning user data. In particular, I am interested in his rights. With these rights, I will render the components. I am thinking of passing this data to components and doing some checks. All routes are in the index.js

```
import {Notfound404} from './components/404/404NotFound'
import {UserContext} from './UserContext'

const Router = () => {

    const [user, setUser] = useState(null)

    return (
        <React.StrictMode>
            <UserContext.Provider value={{user, setUser}}>
                <CookiesProvider>
                    <BrowserRouter>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path={'/'} component={Auth}/>
                            <Route exact path={'/settings'} component={Settings}/>
                            <Route exact path={'/event-logs'} component={EventLog}/>
                            <Route component={Notfound404} status={404}/>
                        </Switch>
                    </BrowserRouter>
                </CookiesProvider>
            </UserContext.Provider>
        </React.StrictMode>
    )
}
```

setting user data in Auth.js

```
import {UserContext} from '../../UserContext'

export const Auth = () => {

    const {user, setUser} = useContext(UserContext)

    const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const [token, setToken] = useCookies(['qr-token'])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (token['qr-token']) window.location.href = '/settings'
    }, [token])

    const credentials = {
        username: username,
        password: password
    }

    const sendCredentials = () => {
        axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/auth/`, credentials, {
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
            }
        })
            .then(resp => {
                setToken('qr-token', resp.data.token);
                setUser(resp.data)
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error.response))
    }

    return !token['qr-token'] &&
        <div className={styles.authContainer}>
            <label htmlFor={'username'}>Username</label>
            <input id={'username'} type={'text'} placeholder={'username'}
                   onChange={evt => setUsername(evt.target.value)}
            />
            <label htmlFor={'password'}>Password</label>
            <input id={'password'} type={'password'} onChange={evt => 
                setPassword(evt.target.value)}/>
            <button onClick={sendCredentials}>Sign In</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

In the index.js I am getting user data after authorization. But in settings.js use data is null

```
export const Settings = () => {

    const {user, setUser} = useContext(UserContext)
    console.log(user) # null
....
}
```

Probably I am doing something wrong and I am asking for your help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the content of the file `UserContext` please?

Comment: Nothing special )  
import {createContext} from 'react'
export const UserContext = createContext(null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Saba indicated, the issue is about refreshing the page which clears the context. This is done by these lines:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (token['qr-token']) window.location.href = '/settings'
}, [token])
```

Don't use the usual redirect methods in Single Page Applications. Instead, use

```
const history = useHistory();
useEffect(() => {
    if (token['qr-token'])
        history.push('/settings');
}, [token])
```

This won't cause a reload of the page and therefore keeps your context alive.

Comment: Work perfectly! Thank you so much. But if the page is refreshed, the data is lost. Maybe as Saba advised to store them in local storage?

Comment: @ВалерийСиволапенко Yes, you'll need some way of persisting the login token. `localStorage` is your best bet with your current setup. Simply persist the qr-token and read it whenever your site is loaded.

Comment: Okay! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think a refresh is happening while redirecting to the setting page. That reload cause the context value to get cleared (simply, because the value of the context is coming from a state and that state gets lost as a result of refresh). To fix this, you can store the auth data data in localStorage and assign the context value to it whenever it gets null.

Comment: I also thought it was because of window.location

Comment: If somehow the user deletes the data from the local storage just log out of it? I just don't know what is the best option for this. I've been doing frontend for a week)

Comment: If localStorage gets cleared and the a page refresh happen, context will be null again. Another approach is as Simon said, to use history.push() which does not cause any refresh. However, if any refresh happens the context will get null again if it is not stored in localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

> useContext() provides a dispatch function that has been passed down
> from the Store component. The dispatch function accepts two arguments,
> a type of action, and a payload for updating the global state. The
> useContext() function will then return an updated global state.

```js
const { state, dispatch } = useContext(MyContext);
```

In your code `setUser` must be triggered with the parameter contains action type and payload.

For example.

```js
setUser({
    type: "SET_USER",
    payload: resp.data
  })
```